# Preshtashop 1.7.2 ajax call NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Created new module freetech
within that 2 controllers
finder and ajax

```
freetech/finder    works fine in browser 
freetech/ajax    works fine in browser
```

finder is calling ajax controller for ajax result

```
<?php

class FreetechAjaxModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController {

    public function initContent() {
        echo "ajax";
    }

}
?>
```

JQuery Code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('ready');
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://localhost:8081/cool2have/module/freetech/ajax',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'text',
                data : '',
                success : function(response){
                    // lert(response); $('#content-wrapper').html(response);
                },
                error: function resultat, statut, erreur) {
                    alert(erreur);
                }
        });
    }
    );

</script>
```

when call ajax controller as ajax call it gives `500 internal server error`

thanks in advance

Comment: That is a server error, check your server logs for what is causing the error

Comment: With the snippet you provided no one can possibly know what goes wrong in the "internal server error" as it is.. in the called server, you must do some investigation there and find out what happens when you call that url in those conditions, have you tried with fiddler, PostMan or something like that?